Disable navigation buttons and Swipe from down to Up
`Is there any way to completely disable navigation buttons or swipe down/up , I've tried out some kiosk mode tutorials but still haven't got it working properly. I can hide the buttons/navigation bar but the user can still swipe down/up to show the navigation buttons / status bar or in other mobile swipe down/up to navigate to the home screen and i don't want the user to exit this page.`ndroid app or android device?
We are looking into making a tablet/mobile application that will be used for educational purposes and it's super important that the user can't exit the application in any way. The app has to be viewed in full screen at all times.`
composable(
    route = Screen.KioskMode.route
) {
    BackHandler(true) {


    }
        KioskMode(navController = navController,)

}

